# Asymptotic behavior of $\int_0^\pi\int_0^R e^{-at\cos\theta}\sin^2\theta J_0(at\sin\theta)\sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta$ as $R \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, indefinite-integrals

Consider the two following functions defined by double integrals
\begin{align}
\varphi_a (R) &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^R e^{-at\cos\theta} \sin^2\theta \,
J_0(at\sin\theta) \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, , \\
\psi_a (R) &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^R e^{-at\cos\theta} \sin^2\theta \,
 J_1(at\sin\theta) \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, ,
\end{align}
wherein $a, R \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$.
It can be shown that $\lim_{R\to\infty} \varphi_a = 2/ (3a)$ and that
$\lim_{R\to\infty} \psi_a = -1/ (3a)$

But how do $\varphi_a(R)$ and $\psi_a(R)$ behave asymptotically to leading order as $R \to \infty$?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Minor point: $$
\varphi _a (R) = \frac{1}{a}\varphi _1 (aR),\quad \psi _a (R) = \frac{1}{a}\psi _1 (aR),
$$i.e., we can assume that $a=1$.

Comment: @Gary i agree. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the exponential [generating function for the Legendre polynomials](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12.E12):
\begin{equation}
 e^{xz}J_{0}\left(z\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{P_{n}\left(x\right)}{n!}z^{n}
\end{equation}
with $z=-t,x=\cos\theta$ the first integral (taken with $a=1$, as remarked by @Gary in a comment) reads
\begin{align}
 \varphi (R) &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^R e^{-t\cos\theta} \sin^3\theta\, J_0(t\sin\theta) \, dt \, d\theta \\
 &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^Rt^nP_n(\cos\theta)\sin^3\theta \, dt \, d\theta\\
 &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}R^{n+1}\int_0^1(1-x^2)P_n(x)\,dx
\end{align}
we supposed valid the interchange of integration and summation and change $x=\cos\theta$ to obtain the latter expression.

When $n$ is even ($n=2p$), we have, by symmetry,
\begin{align}
 w_{2p}&=\int_0^1(1-x^2)P_{2p}(x)\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)P_{2p}(x)\,dx
\end{align}
The orthogonality properties of the Legendre polynomials indicate that the integrals with $p\ge2$ vanish and direct calculation shows that $w_0=2/3,w_2=-2/15$.

When $n$ is odd ($n=2p+1$), we use the tabulated integral ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.17.E39))
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{1}P_{2p+1}\left(x\right)x^{z-1}\,dx=\frac{(-1)^{p}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z\right)_{p}}}{2{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}z\right)_{p+1}}}
\end{equation}
where $(.)_n$ is Pochhammer's symbol, to express
\begin{align}
 w_{2p+1}&=\int_0^1(1-x^2)P_{2p+1}(x)\,dx\\
 &=\frac{(-1)^{p}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{p}}}{2{\left(1\right)_{p+1}}}-\frac{(-1)^{p}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{p}}}{2{\left(2\right)_{p+1}}}
\end{align}
Then, converting the series into generalized hypergeometric functions (GHF),
\begin{align}
 \varphi(R)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}R^{n+1}w_n\\
 &=w_0R+\frac16w_2R^3-\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2p+2)!}w_{2p+1}R^{2p+2}\\
 &=\frac23R-\frac1{45}R^3-\frac12\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^p}{(2p+2)!}R^{2p+2}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{p}}{{\left(1\right)_{p+1}}}-\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{p}}{{\left(2\right)_{p+1}}}\right]\\
 &=\frac23R-\frac1{45}R^3-\frac{R^2}4\left[
 \phantom{}_{2}F_{3}\! \left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2},2,2;-\frac{R^{2}}{4}\right)
 -\frac12\phantom{}_{2}F_{3}\! \left(-\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2},2,3;-\frac{R^{2}}{4}\right)
 \right]
\end{align}
Then the asymptotic behavior follows:
\begin{equation}
 \varphi(R)=\frac23+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(R-\pi/4)}{R^{3/2}}-\frac{21}{8}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(R+\pi/4)}{R^{5/2}}+O(R^{-7/2})
\end{equation}
This result was obtained with a CAS, however it should not be too difficult to derive it from the [asymptotic expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11.E8) of the GHF.

This method should also apply to evaluate the second integral, by differentiating the starting identity
\begin{equation}
 J_0(t\sin\theta)=e^{t\cos(\theta)}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}P_n(\cos\theta)t^n
\end{equation}
w.r.t. $t$ or $\theta$ to obtain an expansion of $J_1$, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Merci Paul! You will be rewarded PTS 50 in about 23 hours for your great answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Merci for the generous bounty. Tell me if you are in trouble with $\psi(R)$, I can try.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de quoi ;) No need for doing that for $\psi$. The picture is clear now. Best greetings, A